# Falsa alarma o alarma falsa?

Tags: vocabulario, expresiones, adjetivos

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "falsa alarma" y "alarma falsa"?

Comment: The collocation is "falsa alarma", and it refers to an unjustified warning (because there was no actual risk or danger). We would only use "alarma falsa" in the unlikely event that an alarm device is counterfeit.

Comment: @diGriz Don't you think the question is clear enough as it is? I think it is, because we don't need any context to find and point out the difference in this specific case.

Comment: @Gustavson - Related Meta post: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2763/9385

Comment: @aparente001 I may have felt prompted to answer as a result of OP's complaint (P. S. Stackexchange is boring.) Igor, next time please do include some research to show the origin of or reason for your question. Thank you!

Comment: Half a page of quibbling and not one line that's interesting or about spanish?

Comment: @Gustavson oops. DIdn't see your answer there. I'll delete my answer and let your comment be the response.